# How to refer to each button when u dynamically create an uknown amount of them?

Tags: c#, button, dynamic

```
Char[] mychars = { ' ' };
            string myText = "Hello how are you";
            string[] names = myText.Split(mychars);
            int idef=0;
            foreach(string x in names)
            {
                Button b = new Button
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Name = "b" + idef,
                    Text = x,
                    Location = new Point(centerLine.Location.X + idef * 100, centerLine.Location.Y),
                };
                b.Click += (sender1, e1) =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text += ((Button)sender1).Text;
                };
                this.Controls.Add(b);
                idef++;
            }

            b0.Text = "change";
```

b0 is a button i created but it doesnt exist in the current context, how can i refer it to itself? Im working in visual studio its a Forms application.

Comment: Hey, please add a little bit more information about the context. Your question doesn't help to illustrate the situation. Fix the tag and briefly describe which platform you are working on before someone gives a downvote and demotivates you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.Controls.Add(b);`

If you are adding the buttons to `this.Controls`, you should be able to access all of them using LINQ. To add its functionality, use:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then, you can get all the buttons in the control:

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

Or all the buttons which names start with the letter 'b':

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("b"));
```

After that, you are able to search in the list of buttons using LINQ:

```
var b0 = buttons.Where(x => x.Name == "b0").SingleOrDefault();
```

Or search the entire `ControlCollection` in `this` without creating the 'buttons' variable. Use the `SingleOrDefault()` method to return one button with a specific name:

```
var b0 = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x => x.Name == "b0").SingleOrDefault();
```

When you then would want to change the button's Text or any other property, simply use:

```
b0.Text = "New Text";
```

To learn more about LINQ visit [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/). All the LINQ methods are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities).

If you wouldn't want to use LINQ for retrieving the buttons, you can simply select all the buttons using a `foreach` loop and the `is` keyword for checking the type:

```
var buttons = new List<Button>();

foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control is Button button)
     {
          buttons.Add(button);
     }
}
```

Or select all the buttons which names start with the letter 'b':

```
var buttons = new List<Button>();

foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control is Button button && button.Name.StartsWith("b"))
     {
          buttons.Add(button);
     }
}
```

You can also select a button with a specific name this way:

```
Button b0 = null;

foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control is Button button && button.Name == "b0")
     {
          b0 = button;
          break;  // break keyword to stop the loop if the button is found
     }
}
```

Then, you are able to edit the properties of the buttons 'b0', although you have to make sure the button is not null:

```
if (b0 is not null)  // checks if button exists
{
     b0.Text = "New Text";
}
```

Comment: whats LINQ? so it essentially searches for buttons?

Comment: LINQ is a query syntax to retrieve/sort/select/modify etc. items which is essentially a set of methods which you can use on lists of objects. In this case we use the `OfType<Button>()` method which searches in the form controls and selects all items with a matching type (in this case a Button, you can replace it with other types to get different controls), as well as the `Where(x => x...)` method which searches in the list and selects all items which a matching condition. You can think of it as a set of complex `foreach` loops which you can quickly use by only calling one short method.

Comment: @Ethereallie As for the syntax itself, there are methods (like `Where()` or `Select()`) and keywords (like `from person in peopleList select person.FirstName`). You can read more about LINQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/) as it's quite powerful and you will probably be using it in the future. You also have a full list of all methods used by LINQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: there is no other way to refer to dynamic controls? this is for my duolingo look alike project and one of the things it has is like word blocks (buttons) that u click and they move to form a sentence. So the thing i have to do is get a sentence from my sql table, separate words from it and randomly shuffle them then take that array and make buttons from each one. Idk how to make them move and then if they are clicked again they should go back (I thought about adding like a spawnlocation property but idk how to do that. so i need to refer to the buttons in order to take their text value.

Comment: BTW we did't learn a lot of this in school but yet we have to self learn stuff. My biggest problem is the program has no use "a program that teaches u languages" that doesnt mean anything to me, idk how languages should be taught so i just tried to copy duolingo. My first problem was saving those practices like are they just a bunch of static forms or are they drawn from some data base, so i decided to go for the database. Now there is a plenty of mistakes probably bcs i didnt plan stuff out i just added as i went.

Comment: Duolingo is quite a complex app to create a desktop version based on (especially in WinForms). You can split the sentence [this way](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split), as for the shuffle you can randomize items making random guids with `.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())`. If you would want to quickly add some properties to a button you can always create a class for each button and put it in the button's Tag property, which can be anything. For more, do research and check what is suitable for the situation, but like I said, it may be quite challenging.

Comment: yeah we just did 1 year of c# and maybe few months of sql but we didn't do implementations of sql in c#, some stuff from duolingo i won't do, like the voice stuff and there aren't any algorythms for when ur good and fast in a practice